# Under what BLS line do "people who want a job but haven’t searched in the last 12 months" show up?

Tags: labor-economics, statistics, unemployment, united-states

I'm trying to understand how this [CNN math](https://edition.cnn.com/interactive/2020/05/business/april-jobs-report-unemployment-rate/) was derived:

> This category — jobless people who “want a job now” but “did not search for work in the previous year” — has hovered around 3 million workers per month for most of the last decade, but it suddenly more than doubled to 6.9 million in April. Because these workers didn’t search for new jobs in the last 12 months, they were not counted in either the unemployment rate or the U6 underemployment rate.

But where are these 6.9 million reported by the BLS? I [see](https://www.bls.gov/news.release/empsit.t15.htm) BLS says "discouraged workers" are actually included in U6...

[image]

So where are these 6.9m "people who want a job but haven’t searched in the last 12 months" reported by the BLS?

Answer (score 1):

That's reported in A-38 under "not in the labor force" but "want a job" and "did not search for work in the previous year". The line/figure doesn't have a U-style indicator.

[image]